# .NET web.config encryption failing!

Tags: asp.net, rsa

Here is what I do:

```
//First delete 
aspnet_regiis -pz MyKeyName 
//Create the container
aspnet_regiis -pc MyKeyName -exp
//Install the key into a machine-level RSA key provider 
aspnet_regiis -pi MyKeyName pathToKeyFile
//Encrypt
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" -prov pathToWebConfigFile

//So that's all good so far. If I want I can now decrypt which runs just fine on the same machine:
aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings"
```

I now take the Encrypted file and bring it to another machine and instal the same key (got from exporting my key using aspnet_regiis -px "MyKeyName" "C:\MyKeyName.xml" -pri).

Now when I run the same decryption command I get an error " Decryption failed... Bad Data..."

What am i missing here???

Comment: hello, did u get a solution for this? its been 3 years now.

Answer (score 1):

With any encryption there will be a public and private key. The private key used to encrypt the data contained in the Web.config file isn't actually written inside that file. This means that if you copy the encrypted Web.config from one server to another, the second server will be unable to decrypt the information.

Basically you have to encrypt and descrypt on the same server.

Comment: I found how to export the private key "aspnet_regiis -px "CustomKeys" "C:\CustomKeys.xml" -pri" but it still doesn't work!!! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650304.aspx#paght000006_webfarmscenarios

Comment: If you try to encrypt the web.config file on the new server then compare them both in a text editor are they different? I guess that would mean that the private key isn't imported correctly onto that server.

Comment: Each configuration file has to be encrypted on the individual machine, so a file encrypted on one server can't be decrypted on another server.